# Grails 3 database-migration-plugin initialization error

Tags: grails, liquibase, grails-3.0

I recently added database-migration-plugin to my grails 3.0.11 app. The problem is when I try to run-app I get a following error:

```
ERROR grails.boot.GrailsApp - Application startup failed
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'springLiquibase_dataSource': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Script text to compile cannot be null!
```

Looks like it can't find changelog.xml in my grails-app/migrations folder. My build.gradle file contains:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:database-migration:2.0.0.RC1"
    }
}
```

and

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'grails-app/migrations'
        }
    }
}
```

I also added the following lines in my application.groovy file:

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileNames = ['changelog.xml']
```

I would by very gratefull for any advice how to make database-migration-plugin work properly.

Edit:

I created changelog.xml file using `$grails dbm-create-changelog` command

I also added to build.gradle (as suggested by `$grails plugin-info database-migration` command):

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.grails.plugins:database-migration:2.0.0.RC1"
}
```

then I changed it to (following official documentation):

```
dependencies {
    runtime "org.grails.plugins:database-migration:2.0.0.RC1"
}
```

and then (as suggested by manual for startup error) I forced liquibase:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.3.2'
    runtime 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:2.0.0.RC1'
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.3.2'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:2.0.0.RC1'
}
```

The problem still remains: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Script text to compile cannot be null!`

Answer (score 8):

We ran into the same problem when upgrading to Grails 3.

A look into the code of the `grails-database-migration` plugin made clear that the configuration parameter is changed from a list `updateOnStartFileNames` to a single value `updateOnStartFileName`.

So when you change your config from

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileNames = ['changelog.xml']
```

to

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileName = 'changelog.xml'
```

it should work again.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar error.  In my case we had some lookup tables where we were populating using a hand crafted script which was included into the main changelog.groovy like:

```
include file: 'data/001-tablex-data.groovy'
```

except the file name was incorrect - it should have been 002-... instead.  The error is basically the same, but there is no reporting to indicate which included file is not being found/parsed, which is a pain.  So if you have manually included files, then look for incorrectly named ones in addition to checking the top-level changelog.groovy or changelog.xml

Comment: This is the right answer, the problem originates when one of the import file is not being found it can be one of them or even the update file name ( changelog.xml or changelog.groovy)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this issue too and in my case, the problem was the order of that block in `build.gradoe`

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'grails-app/migrations'
        }
    }
}
```

It **MUST** be before the `bootRun`, like the below code.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'grails-app/migrations'
        }
    }
}

bootRun {
    jvmArgs(
            '-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always',
            '-noverify',
            '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1',
            '-Xmx1024m')
    sourceResources sourceSets.main
    String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
    systemProperty springProfilesActive, System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
}
```

If you put `sourceSets` after `bootRun` your application will not find the migrations file.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I finally found a solution. Maybe it will help someone someday. So what I did was simply delete changelog.groovy (i switched from XML to Groovy) file. Then I generated a new one with `$grails dbm-create-changelog changelog.groovy`command. As a final step I run `$grails dbm-changelog-sync` and everything started to work just fine.

Comment: This is not a solution for the real problem. You have worked around it by making sure you are using the default changelog script name. My answer solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure:

1. You have set up the changelog, i.e., the file `grails-app/migrations/changelog.xml` exists and is valid.

How you do this depends on your situation.  The plugin's documentation has a section for how to create the file initially.

2. Your datasource is set up to use the database that `changelog.xml` applies to.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for an answer. Jet it is not a solution. I forgot to add my runtime dependency in issue description. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential cause for this problem that we had run into was incorrect capitalization. If changelog.groovy references `path/someFile.groovy` but the actual name is `path/somefile.groovy` then you will get this error. Make sure the path name capitalization matches.