# How to debug grails 3 plugins

Tags: debugging, grails-3.0

It may be a newbie question but very important thou: how can I debug grails 3 plugins? To make question more clear please check out my previous issue: [Grails 3 database-migration-plugin initialization error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132589/grails-3-database-migration-plugin-initialization-error). There is part saying:

```
liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException
```

I would very like to try to debug it my self but I don't know how to get to the source of related plugin and put there a break point or simply print a message to the console.

I am using NetBeans IDE, but I can easily switch to any other IDE.

Answer (score 1):

In Jetbrains at least, you can set Java exception breakpoints for the exception you are getting.  Also, plugins appear in the list of External Libraries in the Project window.  You can expand those libraries and set breakpoints in specific files.

Then, when you run gradle tasks, run them by right clicking the task in the gradle tool window and choose 'debug' instead of 'run'.